# Closures & JavaScript Syntax

Tags: javascript

I ran this in the console to find the value of result but I am stumped as to why it is 122. I cannot figure why, nor can I figure out how bonus is used in the code blow. Could someone explain the value of bonus and how they attained the values of each variable declared at the beginning please. I think it will help me and the rest of the world understand what's going in this learning script:

```
var hidden = mystery(3);
var jumble = mystery3(hidden);
var result = jumble(2);

function mystery ( input ){
    var secret = 4;

    input+=2;

    function mystery2 ( multiplier ) {
        multiplier *= input;

        return secret * multiplier;
    }

    return mystery2;
}

function mystery3 ( param ){
    function mystery4 ( bonus ){
        return param(6) + bonus;
    }

    return mystery4;
}
```

Thank you very much in advance! (i've reviewed many resources and can't quite figure this rather basic one out). :(

Comment: This isn't hard at all, just log out the values and explore which, how and when the functions are execute will get you through.

Comment: Did you even take any debugging steps to look at the intermediate results or to step through it in the debugger to understand your own issue?  This doesn't seem difficult with a little of your own debugging steps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Logging out or even better, writing out the returned values by hand and looking at one statement at a time helps you simplify the problem.

```
var hidden = mystery(3);
```

`mystery(3)` returns the function:

```
function mystery2 ( multiplier ) {
    multiplier *= input;        //notice input is 5
    return secret * multiplier; //  and secret is 4
}
```

<sub>Note that `input` and `secret` in this case will always be constant. This is not always the case though. Normally the reason why closure is used is to encapsulate variables in a private environment and the closure functions provide a way for non-local function to "reach" into the private scope. Those variables are not garbage collected after the function has finished executing because the returned functions still have access to them. Those function can still change the value of the variables inside the function even after the function has already ended.</sub>

---

```
var jumble = mystery3(hidden);
```

`mystery3(hidden)` returns the function:

```
function mystery4 ( bonus ){
    return param(6) + bonus;  //param(6), which points to mystery2 above,
                              //          is just 6*5*4 = 120
}
```

---

```
var result = jumble(2);
```

Well, `jumble(2)`, which "is" `mystery4` above, is just `120 + 2` thus 122.

Answer (score 1):

Well that's a pretty convoluted set of functions, but...

You can think of `var hidden = mystery(3)` as:

```
function mystery2( multiplier ) { 
    multiplier *= 5;
    return 4 * multiplier;
}
```

Then, you can think of `var jumble = mystery3(hidden)` as:

```
function mystery4( bonus ){
    return mystery2(6) + bonus;
}
```

...or

```
function mystery4(bonus) {
    return 120 + bonus; // 120 is the result of 6 *  5 * 4
}
```

And then when you call `jumble(2)` it calls `mystery(bonus)` which does `return 120 + bonus`, or `return 120 + 2;`